# Foundation Orbit Slider Jams on Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I tried converting an orbit slider I made with the Foundation 6 framework into WordPress, however it seems to jam and stop working as soon as it slides to the second post:

```
<ul class="orbit-container">
  <?php $i = 0; ?>
  <?php $slider = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'testimonials', 'orderby' => 'date', 'posts_per_page' => 3)); while($slider->have_posts()) : $slider->the_post(); ?>
    <li class="<?php echo $i == 0 ? 'is-active' : '' ?> orbit-slide">
      <div class="post">
        <blockquote class="post">
          <i class="fa fa-quote-left quotes"></i>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
          <i class="fa fa-quote-right quotes"></i>
        </blockquote>
        <cite><?php the_title(); ?></cite>
      </div><!-- .post -->
    </li>
  <?php $i++; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
```

I have also enqueued the following js files (as well as my custom one in which foundation is triggered):

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js', array(), '3.2.0', true);
wp_enqueue_script('foundation', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/foundation.min.js', array(), '6.3.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('foundation-orbit', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/foundation.orbit.min.js', array(), '6.3.1', true);
```

Could anyone PLEASE help me? I really have no idea as per how to correct this bit of code.
Thank you all in advance.

**UPDATE:**
I had forgotten to paste them on the above code but I also have included the following bullet points below the unordered list:

```
<nav class="orbit-bullets">
  <?php $entries = $slider->post_count; ?>
  <?php for($i=0; $i<$entries; $i++) { ?>
    <button class="<?php echo $i==0 ? 'is-active' : '' ?>" data-slide="<?php echo $i; ?>"></button>
  <?php } ?>
</nav>
```

GENERATED HTML:

```
<ul class="orbit-container">
  <li class="is-active orbit-slide">
    <div class="post">
      <blockquote class="post">
        <i class="fa fa-quote-left quotes"></i>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat...</p>
        <i class="fa fa-quote-right quotes"></i>
      </blockquote>
      <cite>Lorem Ipsum</cite>
    </div><!-- .post -->
  </li>
  <li class=" orbit-slide">
    <div class="post">
      <blockquote class="post">
        <i class="fa fa-quote-left quotes"></i>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <i class="fa fa-quote-right quotes"></i>
      </blockquote>
      <cite>Lorem Ipsum Two</cite>
    </div><!-- .post -->
  </li>
  <li class=" orbit-slide">
    <div class="post">
      <blockquote class="post">
        <i class="fa fa-quote-left quotes"></i>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat!!!</p>
        <i class="fa fa-quote-right quotes"></i>
      </blockquote>
      <cite>Lorem Ipsum Three</cite>
    </div><!-- .post -->
  </li>
</ul>

<nav class="orbit-bullets">
  <button class="is-active" data-slide="0"></button>
  <button class="" data-slide="1"></button>
  <button class="" data-slide="2"></button>
</nav>
```

Comment: `$i` is always 0. All slides are marked active.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response inarilo.
I tried to increment its value as well before closing the while loop, but with no change what-so-ever:
`<?php $i++; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>`

Comment: Are you sure there are more than two slides? Have you checked the generated html?

Comment: Yes, three slides are correctly generated. What seems to happen is that the second seems to load on top of the first one rather than replacing it, therefore jamming the process.

Comment: Can you paste the generated html?

Comment: Have you included all required css? Does it make a difference if the scripts are loaded in the header instead of footer? I can't see anything wrong with the html.

Comment: Except I don't see a line corresponding to`<div class = "orbit" role = "region" data-orbit data-use-m-u-i = "false">`, perhaps that is a factor?

Comment: In terms of CSS files I've just included the foundation.min.css as well as the custom.css file, so I really don't see what else I am missing here...
As for the orbit div, it somehow managed to skip it when I copied the code, but it is correctly generated.
It all seems fine initially, but as soon as an event is triggered the new post tries to display on top of the initial one, consequently jamming the process.

Comment: Can I see the page?

Comment: actually, before that, have you checked if any js errors are being shown in the browser console?

Comment: Hi inarilo,
I would like to say a big **THANK YOU** to you. As it turns out and for whatever reason, my `data-use-m-u-i=""` was set to `true`, and only by comparing it to your code was I then able to spot that out.
So now my orbit is finally sliding as it should, and once again I'd like to thank you ever so much for your time, patience and help.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)